# getting render error like nothing was returned from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements

I have below wrapper kind of conditional wrapper and i am trying to replace with the below condition with conditional wrapper

```
 render: (text) => {
    return (
      <ConditionalWrapper
        condition={isCheckedFn?.(text)}
        wrapper={(ch) => (
          <Badge count={<CheckCircleFilled style={{ color: 'green' }} />}>{ch}</Badge>
        )}
      >
        <ConditionalWrapper
          condition={isSelectable}
          wrapper={(ch) => (
            <Button type="link" onClick={() => action(ch)}>
              {ch}
            </Button>
          )}
        >
          {isEqual(searchedColumn, fieldName) && !isEmpty(searchText) ? (
            <Highlighter
              highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
              searchWords={[searchText]}
              autoEscape
              textToHighlight={text.toString()}
            />
          ) : (
            text
          )}
        </ConditionalWrapper>
      </ConditionalWrapper>
    );
  }
```

and the below is conditional wrapper component

```
const ConditionalWrapper = ({ condition, wrapper, children }) =>
  condition ? wrapper(children) : children;

export default ConditionalWrapper;
```

and then i am trying to replace below rendering highlighter with conditional wrapper

```
{isEqual(searchedColumn, fieldName) && !isEmpty(searchText) ? (
            <Highlighter
              highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
              searchWords={[searchText]}
              autoEscape
              textToHighlight={text.toString()}
            />
          ) : (
            text
          )}
```

and after that it looks like this

```
render: (text) => {     
    return (
      <ConditionalWrapper
        condition={isCheckedFn?.(text)}
        wrapper={(ch) => (
          <Badge count={<CheckCircleFilled style={{ color: 'green' }} />}>{ch}</Badge>
        )}
      >
        <ConditionalWrapper
          condition={isSelectable}
          wrapper={(ch) => (
            <Button type="link" onClick={() => action(ch)}>
              {ch}
            </Button>
          )}
        >
         <ConditionalWrapper  // getting error in this conditional wrapper
            condition={isEqual(searchedColumn, fieldName) && !isEmpty(searchText)}
            wrapper={(text) =>
              (<Highlighter
              highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
              searchWords={[searchText]}
              autoEscape
              textToHighlight={text.toString()}
            />)
            }
            text
           />
        </ConditionalWrapper>
      </ConditionalWrapper>
    );
  },
```

with this code getting an error like as below

> Error: ConditionalWrapper(...): Nothing was returned from render. This
> usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing,
> return null.

I don't know what I am doing wrong with above code could any one please let me know where i am doing wrong and is this proper way to use that conditional wrapper.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: is there anything not clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this because third `ConditionalWrapper` has no `children` (I guess it is a typo? As `text` is passed as prop). Something like this should work

```
<ConditionalWrapper
  condition={isEqual(searchedColumn, fieldName) && !isEmpty(searchText)}
  wrapper={(ch) => (
    <Highlighter
      highlightStyle={{ backgroundColor: '#ffc069', padding: 0 }}
      searchWords={[searchText]}
      autoEscape
      textToHighlight={ch.toString()}
    />
  )}
>
  {text}
</ConditionalWrapper>
```

Comment: thanks for suggestion and instead of text do i need to pass something and i am getting warning like `text` is already defined in upper here `render:(text)`

Comment: Yep, sorry! Probably the best solution is to just simply `wrapper={(ch) => (` instead of `wrapper={(text) => (`. This way you will fix this warning and keep it consistent across of all the `ConditionalWrapper` components

Comment: sorry, but where do i need to use that `ch` since i am using text.Tostring() at here `textToHighlight={text.toString()}` before converting it into conditionalwrapper

Comment: Edited original answer, it should be clear now - note that `wrapper` is invoked with children of `ConditionalWrapper` component. So probably `ch` is a better name